# How can I send value inside select event?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have onchange event inside a select input, I try execute a javascript function but I need insert inside one value get from php as follows:

```
<?php
    print "<select name='sel_reg' id='testsel2' onchange=\"loaddiver('city',this.value ".$_REQUEST['data_loc'].");\">";
?>
```

The problem come from **$_REQUEST['data_loc']** if i put inside no works nothing if i don´t use this , all works perfectly , i need get this 2 values inside but i don´t know how i can do this

Comment: did you tried using echo instead of print ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a comma after this.value:

```
onchange="loaddriver('city', this.value, $_REQUEST['data_loc']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
<?php

?>
        <select name="sel_reg" id="testsel2" onchange="loaddiver('city',this.value, <?php echo $_REQUEST['data_loc'] ;?>)">

<?php
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing: Your data is uneascaped, so if some html special char ("'<> etc.) occurrs in the string it'll mess up your html.

Second thing: You need apostrophes around your string and you need to add a comma after this.value:

```
<?php
    print "<select name='sel_reg' id='testsel2' onchange=\"loaddiver('city', this.value, '".htmlentities($_REQUEST['data_loc'], ENT_QUOTES)."');\">";
?>
```